# driver 8812au install with NO ethernet access

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

I apologize in advance if this is covered in a previous post. However, I've searched and searched and have only found solutions for people with access to an ethernet connection. I am currently running windows 8.1 using my netgear A6100 wireless USB adapter, and unfortunately it is the only access I have to the internet. According to previous posts i've found, such as

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2235778

and

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2240631

I need the 8812au driver in order to get wireless access from my netgear A6100.

this would be great

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
cd ~/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8812au
```

except I can't install anything via this route because I do not have a temporary ethernet connection.

My question is, is there any way I can download this driver in windows, save it to a storage device, and open it in ubuntu and compile it offline?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you quite certain you have an 8812au device? Please edit your question to add the result of: lsusb Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install TP-LINK Archer T4U driver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/802205/how-to-install-tp-link-archer-t4u-driver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. On another computer go to that github site:
   https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux and download
   the zip (bottom right)
2. Put that zip on a flash drive
3. Boot into ubuntu
4. Unzip the zip with `unzip [file name]` or do it by right clicking in
   your file manager
5. cd to that folder (step 4 in your steps) and follow your steps from
   there.

EDIT: You'll probably need build-essential if it's not already installed:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/build-essential

Linux headers generic here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-headers-generic

Comment: @musher- It won't compile without build-essential and linux-headers, will it?

Comment: @chili555 good point, I missed that bit. Will edit that in

Comment: @musher- And all their dependencies, too.

Comment: @chili555 You're guys are awesome. I got it to work for any live boot but you are right, on an actual install, I still need build essentials and linux headers generic. I downloaded them as tar.gz and have them on my external hd but have no idea how to manually install them...any tips? Theyre not .Deb so i cant just use synaptic. sorry I'm a noob. I've never had to deal with not having ether net before.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to change "sudo modprobe 8812au" to "sudo modprobe rtl8812au".

Answer (score 0):

I wana share this and give some credit for him! working great with Ubuntu 17.10. I think it will work debian, mint also. Original link https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8812au-driver-5.2.9

**My guide for you**

download:
https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8812au-driver-5.2.9/archive/master.zip

Unzip it!

Open terminal in that folder (right click open terminal) then:

```
sudo dpkg -i gord-rtl8812au-dkms_1.0-13_amd64.deb
```

unplug/plug it in and wola! Why it has to be so hard all the time? ;)

If you want to remove it:

```
sudo dpkg -P gord-rtl8812au-dkms
```