# How to install TP-LINK Archer T4U driver?

Tags: networking, drivers

I bought the wireless adapter to use with a computer without internet access but I can't figure out how to install it with just a USB with the driver on it. I've read a few articles on how to install the driver but they all require me to have internet access and I don't have internet. I'm completely new to Ubuntu. If you can help that would be great. Thanks! 
Ps: I have the latest version of Ubuntu as of 7-5-16.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Please download this file on some other computer and transfer it to the desktop of the subject computer: https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/archive/master.zip Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now, in a terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8812au
```

Now that we have the wireless working correctly, we'll refine this a bit.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dkms
cd ~/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master
sudo cp -R . /usr/src/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-1.0
sudo dkms add -m rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux -v 1.0
sudo dkms build -m rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux -v 1.0
sudo dkms install -m rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux -v 1.0
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what exactly do the "refine" steps accomplish?

Comment: The refinement adds the `dkms` process. The driver will be compiled automatically for you if there is a newer linux-image installed. Highly recommended and thank you, @Eliah Kagan.

Comment: actually - on ARMBIAN and on Debian-like systems - no need in "refine part" - it works fine after `make install` and `modprobe`

Comment: So awesome !!! 
This works even with Archer t4u AC1300 while the official drivers from the TP-Link don't compile. 
I tried downloading and building source from TPlink site from here: http://nl.tp-link.com/download/Archer-T4U_V2.html#Driver but that did not compile on my Ubuntu 17. 
But this GitHub source worked like a charm !!!

Comment: @revolutionary,  what are the exact steps to get the driver for the AC1300?  Do you just replace '-v 1.0' by '-v 2.0' in instructions?  So, for example, you use the same github source for the driver?

Comment: It turns out that the very same steps as above make my ac1300 work too!

Comment: @MátéWierdl - do you actually get "802.11A/C"? These instructions are awesome and worked for me to, but when I do an `sudo lshw -C network` I'm getting: `wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn` (which indicates there is no a/c - I think?).

Comment: @Vanessa Deagan, I get the same thing, so no AC, I suppose. Also, the darn thing is flaky: after a while, it not only drops the connection but cannot detect any network.  If I take it out of the USB slot and reinsert, it works again.

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu Mate 18.04 and works like a charm.

Comment: this seems to be the best solution, but it is not working for my case, I get the wifi symbol the no visible networks are found, so I just have an empty list on ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @EnmanuelDurán Please start a new question and include the results of the wireless script from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: it is not quite clear to me how I can run a script without an internet connection. @chili555

Comment: @EnmanuelDurán Download the script on a USB drive, run it and put the result back on the USB drive and post it.

Comment: done @chili555 https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3pjxnpMzwY/

Comment: Also, here the new question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182192/ubuntu-not-recognizing-archer-t4u-us-3-0-properly @chili555

Answer (score 12):

This driver can be installed from the official Ubuntu repositories by

```
sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms
```

Comment: That's cool, but you have to have a working Internet connection first before using it. Kinda Catch-22.

Comment: It is not a catch if you know how install packages offline.

Comment: Also this doesn't install the same thing. T4U v2 doesn't work with this unfortunately. Compiling it from source and creating a dkms package does work like a charm though.

Comment: Does not work for T4U plush on 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 4):

Works on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with kernel head v5.3.xxx using this repo. which you will need to git clone into a local folder

https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu

```
git clone https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu
```

Make sure you have `build-essentials` and `dkms`

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms
```

After cloning, `cd` into that folder and run

```
cd rtl8822bu
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Then connect to your Wi-Fi (Hopefully, both 2.4GHz and 5GHz should be detectable now)

Next, follow these steps to refine the installation and for an automatic rebuild on Ubuntu kernel image updates

```
sudo dkms add .
sudo dkms install -m 88x2bu -v 1.1
```

Comment: this worked for me on Mint 20 - thank you!

Comment: This worked with ubuntu 20.10, thank you

Comment: Worked with mint ulyana as well, AC1300.