# TP-Link Archer T4U driver issue

Tags: networking, drivers

I'm trying to install the driver for the TP-Link Archer T4U Wi-Fi Dongle.

I've got it manually installed using [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802205/how-to-install-tp-link-archer-t4u-driver), however, it won't actually connect to my network. It just continuously asks for the Wi-Fi password.

When I check Additional Drivers in the Software & Updates app, it shows up as `Unknown: Unknown` and has the option `Do not use the device` selected. I can select `Continue using a manually installed driver`, but then it won't allow me to Apply Changes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The driver and method in your link are correct so, before any further troubleshooting, make sure your router has the proper wireless encryption settings: WPA2-AES only. Not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Reboot router and PC and try again.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the router... however, I don't think that is the problem. Everything seems to work fine, aside from the fact that I cannot make the computer "Continue using a manually installed driver" because the "Apply Changes" button remains greyed out...