# How to install driver for TP-Link Archer T9E V1 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, drivers, tp-link

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and neither wire connection works nor wireless.

Now I have bought a PCI adapter from https://www.tp-link.com/us/download/Archer-T9E.html#videos.
I have followed the link: [How to install TP-LINK Archer T4U driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802205/how-to-install-tp-link-archer-t4u-driver/802209#802209)
but it didn't work for me:

```
~/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master$ sudo modprobe rt18812au
modprobe: FATAL: Module rt18812au not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-38-generic
```

Does anyone know what does it mean or how can solve this ?

Comment: You may have a typo - it is `rtl` (with lowercase `L`, not digit on `1`).  
Try `sudo modprobe rtl8812au` instead of `sudo modprobe rt18812au`. Also you may try to install other driver with: `sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms`. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1029402/edit) and add output of `lspci -knn | grep -A3 "Network\|Wireless"`.

Comment: I tried sudo modprobe rtl8812au nothing happen after I have typed the password! Then I tried sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms it gave: E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have internet while you install Ubuntu it will install the T9E driver by itself. I sadly do not know how to do it after install.
I do have a working T9E driver. If you know any way I can help do ask.

Comment: I have first installed ubuntu 16.04 with wire connection (I don't know if I had internet access during installation) and after the installation I couldn't get access to internet!

Comment: When you installed it, do you remember if the option about "Install drivers while installing Ubuntu, this will save time after installation" or something like that was an option or if it was greyed out? if it was greyed out you did not have internet. Just installed Ubuntu 18.04 3-4 times yesterday because of exactly this.

Comment: I have also selected that option during installation. 
I bought  and mounted the PCI after I have installed ubuntu. so if can not solve this then maybe I should reinstall ubuntu ?

Comment: It will work for sure if you have it installed in the computer while you install Ubuntu and have internet. It's probably not the correct way of handling things.. but it will get the job done.

Comment: Thanks @Bismuth83 I have internet know. It was solved by reinstallation.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. The driver wasn't  install by itself:

Run

> apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade

Reboot and run

> apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
>
> modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
>
> modprobe wl

And reboot again

Link to topic when i found solution:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381848/installing-wifi-drivers-for-14e443a0-rev-3-broadcom-pcie-device-cant-find-bc?newreg=80f009f225c94792b01c46e3d6c4b062

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I just fell over something that could help you. 
I use the T9E network card as well and everything works for me:

1. Open the **Software & Updates** application
2. Go to the **Additional Drivers** tab
3. Look for the **Broadcom Limited: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter** device (this is your TP-Link)
4. Choose the **Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary)** option to enable it

Comment: I can confirm I have my T9E working with this driver

Comment: This should be an **edit** to your previous (accepted) answer, as they are *both* T9 related.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying a T4U driver when you have a T9E card?
The T4U is a USB device uses a Realtek chip. The T9E is a pcie card and it uses a Broadcom chip hence you need to use the Broadcom wl driver.