# Ubuntu broken after upgrade, upgrade was frozen at last stage. What to do next?

Tags: upgrade

So the upgrade from 18.04 to 19.10 is hanging at the clean up stage. Removing libcdd-tools. Terminals will no longer open. I can still open XTerm.

Should I just bit the bullet and restart?

UPDATE: I rebooted. The install process had crashed. Now takes a long time to start up, is offline, screen res off etc. Not sure what state it is in. Are there any principles in the upgrade process that mean it can rerun. It is now reporting 19.10 as the version.

UPDATE: See the comments below for the steps I have tried. Basically, I had to do dpkg --configure -a then redo the upgrade to finish it up. Reboot. Reinstall all the drivers. Wifi is still busted when it was working before. Probably need a new tplink driver.

[Ubuntu 18.04.1 and TP-Link Archer T4U(EU) v2.0 nightmare (RTL8812AU chipset)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067513/ubuntu-18-04-1-and-tp-link-archer-t4ueu-v2-0-nightmare-rtl8812au-chipset)

[Ubuntu 18.04.1 and TP-Link Archer T4U(EU) v2.0 nightmare (RTL8812AU chipset)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067513/ubuntu-18-04-1-and-tp-link-archer-t4ueu-v2-0-nightmare-rtl8812au-chipset)

Comment: Boot into recovery mode by holding Shift key when system starts to boot and entering into "Adavnced Options for Ubuntu". Then select root and press Enter. Run `dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: Am logged in normally, can't get to recovery mode for some reason. get this: 

sudo dpkg -- configure -a
dpkg: error: need an action option

Comment: Am trying this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/346678/how-do-i-resume-a-release-upgrade

Comment: Now trying this: sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

Comment: There's no whitespace between `--` and `configure`.

Comment: Yeah, got that eventually :) ... almost back to normal I think. Somehow ALL the drivers got wiped. Still chasing wifi.