# How do I install T4U archer wireless adapter driver without internet?

Tags: make

I'm trying to install the drivers for my TP-Link T4U Archer adapter on an Ubuntu 20 fresh install. I don't have build-essentials installed because no internet, so I don't have Make. I tried to install build-essentials from the Deb file, but, to install, it requires as a dependency ... Make ... Is there a Deb file with all dependencies necessary to do this?

Comment: Hi Sam, is it possible to tether your phone with a USB cable so that you can connect to the internet via your phone temporarily?

Comment: Also, looking at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067513/ubuntu-18-04-1-and-tp-link-archer-t4ueu-v2-0-nightmare-rtl8812au-chipset there's a comment by @cass that suggests that from Ubuntu 19.04 and onwards you can run 'sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms' as the drivers are available in the Ubuntu repositories now. AbrahamBrookes also helpfully suggested that you will probably need to run 'sudo apt install dkms' beforehand. This might sidestep the need to install anything else ('make' and 'build-essentials') until you've got the wifi working on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

First, determine what dependencies the make package has. (Offhand, I can't think of what they might be, but [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128524/how-to-list-dependent-packages-reverse-dependencies) are a few suggestions how to identify them.)

Do you have the medium you installed from (e.g., USB stick, CD-ROM?). If so, mount that device, & use one of the solutions suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt).

Not sure which will work for you in the end, but unfortunately some solutions only come thru trial & error.