# Having trouble installing a TP-link driver

Tags: networking, drivers

I am unable to connect through an Ethernet cable at the moment so I tried to install the drivers for my TP-link archer T4UH V1 but it’s very confusing as I am completely new to Linux. When I follow the commands from the instruction manual it says syntax error even when directly copying the command onto the terminal.

Can anyone help me to install this driver?

Answer (score 0):

Please download this file on some other computer and transfer it to the desktop of the subject computer: https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/archive/master.zip Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now, in a terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8812au
```

Now that we have the wireless working correctly, we'll refine this a bit.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dkms
cd ~/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master
sudo cp -R . /usr/src/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-1.0
sudo dkms add -m rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux -v 1.0
sudo dkms build -m rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux -v 1.0
sudo dkms install -m rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux -v 1.0
```

Credit: [How to install TP-LINK Archer T4U driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802205/how-to-install-tp-link-archer-t4u-driver)

Comment: Thank you so much abdulla, you are very helpful. I encounter a problem when executing these commands. So I go to the file location on the desktop but when I type in the command “make” it says a bunch of stuff and at the end it says “Makefile:1584 recipe for target ‘modules’ failed make: *** [modules] error 2. Do you know what my problem is?

Comment: Also I do have the tplink drivers downloaded if that helps?

Comment: Share all error log you see on terminal

Comment: daniel@ThugLifeSweg1 ~ $ cd ~/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master
daniel@ThugLifeSweg1 ~/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master $ make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-38-generic/build M=/home/daniel/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-38-generic'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
arch/x86/Makefile:140: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
  CC [M]  /home/daniel/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_cmd.o           I will post many as there arent enough characters :(

Comment: In file included from ./include/linux/cgroup-defs.h:16:0,
                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:61,
                 from ./include/linux/kasan.h:4,
                 from ./include/linux/slab.h:118,
                 from /home/daniel/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/include/osdep_service_linux.h:29,
                 from /home/daniel/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/include/osdep_service.h:41,
                 from /home/daniel/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/include/drv_types.h:32,
       from /home/daniel/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:

Comment: Edit and add the log on the question.

Comment: okay so its even too long for that. The problem making it too long are these lines:  ./include/linux/percpu-refcount.h:1:1: error: null character(s) ignored [-Werror]
   d i s p o s � �ti t i o n = " s t a g e d " > < u p d a t e C o m p o n e n
 ^             there are many of them and then I will post the other lines that come after that.

Comment: In file included from ./include/net/netprio_cgroup.h:17:0,
                 from ./include/linux/netdevice.h:48,
                 from /home/daniel/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/include/osdep_service_linux.h:35,
                 from /home/daniel/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/include/osdep_service.h:41,
                 from /home/daniel/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/daniel/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
./include/linux/cgroup.h: In function ‘css_get’:

Comment: ./include/linux/cgroup.h:295:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘percpu_ref_get’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 percpu_ref_get(&css->refcnt);
 ^
./include/linux/cgroup.h: In function ‘css_get_many’:
./include/linux/cgroup.h:308:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘percpu_ref_get_many’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]  percpu_ref_get_many(&css->refcnt, n);  ^ ./include/linux/cgroup.h: In function ‘css_tryget’:

Comment: ./include/linux/cgroup.h:325:10: error: implicit declaration of function ‘percpu_ref_tryget’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   return percpu_ref_tryget(&css->refcnt);
          ^
./include/linux/cgroup.h: In function ‘css_tryget_online’:
./include/linux/cgroup.h:342:10: error: implicit declaration of function ‘percpu_ref_tryget_live’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   return percpu_ref_tryget_live(&css->refcnt);
          ^

Comment: ./include/linux/cgroup.h: In function ‘css_put’:
./include/linux/cgroup.h:355:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘percpu_ref_put’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   percpu_ref_put(&css->refcnt);
   ^
./include/linux/cgroup.h: In function ‘css_put_many’:
./include/linux/cgroup.h:368:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘percpu_ref_put_many’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   percpu_ref_put_many(&css->refcnt, n);
   ^

Comment: cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:294: recipe for target '/home/daniel/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/daniel/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1524: recipe for target '_module_/home/daniel/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/daniel/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-38-generic'
Makefile:1584: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2

Comment: daniel@ThugLifeSweg1 ~/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master $ sudo make install[sudo] password for daniel: 
install -p -m 644 rtl8812au.ko  /lib/modules/4.10.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
install: cannot stat 'rtl8812au.ko': No such file or directory
Makefile:1590: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
daniel@ThugLifeSweg1 ~/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master $

Comment: thats all of it I am so sorry for spamming you like this. Thanks again

Comment: How about trying the command after using `su` command? Enter `su` then enter your password, after that try the above command.

Comment: @abdulla_malik I think you should have simply marked this as a duplicate of my answer in the link.

Comment: No exactly. Daniel using a different devices. I'm expecting no kernel module made for this device. Let's see what happens.