# Ubuntu not recognizing Archer T4U US 3.0 properly

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, tp-link

I recently formatted my computer and bought a wireless adapter for it Archer T4U US 3.0 from tp link.

I have been trying to get it to work but at first it did not recognize the wifi adapter, so I tried this solution:
https://askubuntu.com/a/802209/592069

After trying the solution I now get the symbol of wifi in the top but it does not recognize any networks from my local I have both signals 2.4ghz and 5.8ghz, but none of them work.

The main reason why I bought this new adapter is to be able to connect to 5.8ghz so that is the main frequency I am trying to connect to.

An active user from the answer that i tried before recommended me to post the results from a script that is posted in [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180)

The result is https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3pjxnpMzwY/

Also attaching a couple of images of how everything looks in my OS:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, we search for your device ID, in this case, the usb.id 2357:0115. We find the usually very reliable wikidevi: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_Archer_T4U_v3 It suggests that the correct driver is not rtl8812au but 88x2bu. I suspect that rtl8812au was correct for an earlier version of the T4U; v2 or v1, perhaps. I am surprised that the rtl8812au driver works even partially.

Let's install the probable better driver:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dkms git
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959
sudo dkms add ./rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v 5.3.1
sudo modprobe -r rtl8812au
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

If the wireless works as expected, let's blacklist the incorrect driver:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8812au"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Comment: is it possible to use `make clean` and then `make` instead of dkms? I have no internet connection to install with sudo apt sadly. I also tried downloading the .deb package for bionic but it is not found when executing it in the terminal.

Comment: I have used `sudo make` and `sudo make install` instead of using `dkms` and it just worked like a charm, thanks a lot, you have no idea how helpful this was.

Comment: Now that you have internet connectivity, I recommend that you undertake the dkms process so that you needn't recompile with every kernel update. Glad it's working!

Comment: Done, your steps with dkms worked properly.

Comment: @chili555 after one hour of trying different solutions finally one that works. Thanks you kind sir.