# How would I install / use my specific TpLink Realtek USB Wireless Adapter into Ubuntu 20.04 LTS without internet connection?

Tags: wireless, usb, realtek, tp-link

I use a TpLink Archer, it's a Realtek, and I want to use it / install it into my Ubuntu. I have 2 drives, the first drive (C:) is Windows, which the USB Wireless Adapter works fine there, I just need it to work on my Ubuntu (D:) drive. My Ubuntu version is 20.04 LTS.

Here's more information of the USB: https://deviwiki.com/wiki/TP-LINK_Archer_T4U_v3

ID: 2357:0115

WI1 chip1: Realtek RTL8812BU

How can I install this into my Ubuntu? I am having trouble, and I've been searching everywhere but couldn't find a solution.

**Edited:**

I cannot install any sudo softwares, so I don't know how I could install any of this (may be no internet connection?). The only "internet" source I have is my USB, which I can install stuff from my Windows computer.

**Please read:**

This question is **not duplicated**, it's a different driver. **Do not use the github in the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185952/need-rtl8814au-driver-for-kernel-5-3-on-ubuntu-19-10) from the duplicated response**

Comment: Connect using your phone and install a driver.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: TPLink Archer is not supported out-of-the-box (TPLink's decsion, not ours). You "just" need to download the driver source code and compile it. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/802205/how-to-install-tp-link-archer-t4u-driver for an example of how to do it. It's not an activity I recommend for beginners.

Comment: Connect your phone to USB and enable USB modem in the phone. Then find an anser for your chip and install the drivers.

Comment: @user535733 Is that link also support my USB Type/ID/Info, like the Chip and ID?

Comment: It's an example. It's up to you to confirm that whatever you download is the correct source code for your *chipset*.

Comment: I've found a github regarding my chip. Should I just basically do the same steps as that question link you sent?

Comment: @user535733 I can't install any package, I can't install make. I don't know if it's because no internet, or what. That makes it **impossible** to even install this Wireless Adapter.

Comment: It's a different chip, I'm RTL8812BU, so I need to find one github that is RTL8812BU, or I may be wrong

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! Now it works beautifully! I actually already had a bluetooth so I connected my phone and use my Phone Personal Hotspot. I also had a sudo issue but I was able to solve it by killing a sudo process. Thank you so much!!

Comment: This question is **not duplicated**, it's a different driver. **Do not use the github in the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185952/need-rtl8814au-driver-for-kernel-5-3-on-ubuntu-19-10) from the duplicated response**