# I just installed Ubuntu on my desktop PC, but my Wi-Fi attachment isn't working anymore -- there's only a wired internet option

Tags: wireless, internet

I need to connect to the internet but the USB-attached thing I use for Wi-Fi doesn't seem to be working on Ubuntu. Any help?

This is what outputs when I enter `lsusb`:

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0451:8140 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB8041 4-Port Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 2516:0057 Cooler Master Co., Ltd. MasterKeys S
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0451:8142 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB8041 4-Port Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c08b Logitech, Inc. G502 HERO Gaming Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2357:0115 2357:0115 TP-Link 802.11ac NIC
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

My USB adapter is a "TP-Link Archer T4U AC1300 High Gain Wireless MU-MIMO USB Adapter."

Comment: Likely you need to install a driver for the USB wifi adapter.  Run `lsusb` in the command line and copy-paste the output into your question here as an edit so we can identify the wifi adapter and requisite software you may need to install (you may have to hook up to a wired connection temporarily to get the software)

Comment: I think you need this questoin: https://askubuntu.com/questions/802205/how-to-install-tp-link-archer-t4u-driver

Comment: Right, sorry, I edited my question.

Comment: That adapter uses a chipset that has outdated drivers in the packaging requiring manual compilation of a suitable driver.  Unfortunately, for all that you'll need a wired connection to start with, and the linked question.

Comment: @ThomasWard Can I not compile it onto a USB then download it onto my PC?

Comment: @ThomasWard Alright, I did all the steps -- my USB adapter flashes green now and the Wi-Fi tab in Settings shows up. However, when I try to connect to my home network, I get an error saying "Connection failed: Activation of network connection failed".