# Wifi usb not working Ubuntu server/desktop 20.04.1 TP-link archer t4u ac1200

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager

I have a TP-link archer t4u ac1200 which isn't working on Ubuntu. I tried almost all the drivers I could find on the internet but they aren't working. Reinstalled the server 2 times now for a fresh start.

When I type `lsusb` I see the USB listed in the list. But when I type `iwconfig` I don't see any `wlan`.
`nmcli radio wifi on` didn't work also. [lsusb output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56iFr.png)

Edit: added `lsusb` screenshot

Comment: Is this https://askubuntu.com/questions/802205/how-to-install-tp-link-archer-t4u-driver  helpfull?

Comment: @nobody already tried that. It's not working.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of: `lsusb`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 updated the question with an image.

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please unplug the device. Next, with a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wireless-tools wpasupplicant
```

In our chat, we determined that you have a driver rtl8812au loaded on your system and that it was, upon examining dmesg, throwing numerous errors. We blacklisted it.

I recommended that you try another, more current version:

```
wget https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/archive/v5.6.4.2.zip
unzip v5.6.4.2.zip 
cd rtl8812au-5.6.4.2/
sudo make dkms_install
```

Reboot

After the reboot, the wireless was working. Next, please configure netplan as outlined in the example:

```
cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/wireless.yaml
```

Comment: Please also show us the result of: `sudo modprobe 8812au && dmesg | grep 8812` as well as: `sudo dkms status` Thanks.

Comment: Results: [link](https://imgur.com/a/Lpl0Dvy)

Comment: "Device or resource busy" Very interesting! Let's see: `lsmod` Perhaps one of the other drivers you tried is interfering.

Comment: This is btw again a fresh install. I've only tried [Link to another askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802205/how-to-install-tp-link-archer-t4u-driver) 

[These are the screenshots of lsmod](https://imgur.com/a/BHPM5a5)

Comment: I also want: `modinfo 8812au | grep filename` as well as: `modinfo rtl8812au | grep filename` and, finally: `dmesg | grep -i rtl` Very interesting case you have there!!

Comment: [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/CT8XcVz) Here you go.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117520/discussion-between-chili555-and-neavehni).